# If my app don't have activity how to use KeyChain.choosePrivateKeyAlias or are there any way to select certificate and private key from keystore?

Tags: java, android

In android we can use KeyChain.choosePrivateKeyAlias to select available private keys and corresponding certificate chains from keystore, but this method only can be used in an activity, because the first parameter of this method is an activity, if there is no activity in my app, how can I get certificate and private keys.

Comment: "if there is no activity in my app" -- unless your app is pre-installed on an Android device, or your app is a plugin for some other app, your app will never run. Beyond that, add a `Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar` activity that you can start when needed to use those `KeyChain` APIs.

Comment: @CommonsWare, thanks. Since I can change Rom code, I add a new method in KeyChain, which can accept context as a parameter.